# HttpClient hangs on request

Tags: c#

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days.

C#, universal windows

I'm trying to access a device in my house that is web enabled.  In looking at the API I should be able to make the following call:

```
{ "id" : "req-1", "url" : "/stable/av/", "method" : "browse" }
```

In fact, if I go into fiddler and send that to the device manually I get a response.

I'm using the following code:

```
try
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
    {
        var _req = new SendRequest();
        _req.id = "rec-100";
        _req.url = "/stable/av/";
        _req.method = "browse";

        var _json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_req);

        using (var content = new StringContent(_json.ToString(),Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
        {
            using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(baseAddress, content).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    }

    var _Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(responseData);

    var item = new ZoneInfo();
    item.szIPAddress = szIPAddress;
    item.szZoneName = _Response.result.item.title;
    lstZones.Add(item);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

The app hangs on the `httpClient.PostAsync(...`

In fiddler when it hits the line for the httpClient.PostAsync(... I see the properly formed request getting sent: (this is copied and pasted from fiddler) `{"id":"rec-100","url":"/stable/av/","method":"browse"}`

But then I've got messages like this which scroll like crazy (10 / second) until I stop the application.

> {"resultId":"492bfa78-b778-4696-ad7c-c0f6a7733c6f","customData":"{\"type\":\"SamplePoints\",\"begin\":{\"h\":0,\"l\":0},\"end\":{\"h\":5,\"l\":-1002889776},\"samples\":436}","dwSessionId":"c533eca5-9ea7-4348-81bd-1920f8ee03da","dwRequestId":"e428bd3c-9d41-479c-993f-325fbfbb4adb"}

This is not the data I get when I post manually...

I'm not as concerned at the moment with the "hang", I'm more concerned about getting the correct data back.

Comment: but if you are concerned about getting the correct data back, then the client code is irrelevant. We need to know who is the server serving the response what what it is doing

Comment: Its a home audio system internal to my network only...  I'm just trying to get the basic information from the device. The above JSON request is listed in their documentation.

Comment: Are you sending all of the appropriate headers?

Comment: Try using the PostAsJsonAsync method instead of post async

Comment: Does that exist with universal windows?  I'm not seeing it...